# Textarea alike but for only one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Something I like about the textarea element is that allows automatic spell checker. This is not happening with input text element. I need an element like textarea that will only show one line and never go to a next line even if the user press enter. I tried row='1' but doesn't matter if the user press enter the content moves to a next line. This could also be a react component. Exist something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
textarea {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

Comment: I did the React's equivalent to your idea and all worked!!

Comment: i think `overflow:hidden;` should be `overflow-y:hidden;`.

Comment: After some characters typed the characters typed are not visible. Around 70 to 90 characters its happening

Answer (score 2):

As your question tagged ReactJS

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  handleTextArea = (e) =>{
    let lineCount = 0;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      lineCount++;
    }
    if (lineCount >= 1) { // set here how may lines you want
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <textarea onKeyDown={this.handleTextArea}>only one line</textarea>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

[image: Edit x3pvn9k20o]